# Elasticsearch prefix query not working on date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents in elasticsearch, and I'd like to apply prefix query on `logtime` field, but nothing would return.

```
      {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "fluentd",
    "_id" : "6Cn38mMBMKvgU4HnnURh",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "logtime" : "2018-06-11 03:08:02,117",
      "userid" : "",
      "payload" : "40",
      "qs" : "[['I have a dream, that everybody'], ['the'], ['steins']]"
    }
  }
```

the prefix query is

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "query": {"prefix" : { "logtime" : "2018-06-11" }}}'
```

Could someone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to fetch All documents of date `2018-06-11`.

Comment: @Richa yes, this is my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) in that case like

```
{
 "query": {
  "range": {
  "createdDate": {
    "gte":"2018-06-11",
    "lte": "2018-06-11",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Hope it helps.